# Replacing ONE specific duplicate in list of duplicates in python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list of lists of words, some of which are duplicates.

```
L = [['I'], ['like'], ['candy'], ['end'], ['do'], ['you'], ['end'], ['okay'], ['end']]
```

What I am trying to do is to shorten the list so that it ends after the first ['end']. I have tried to find the index of the second ['end'] and replacing it with another word, and then telling the program to only print out the list until the index of that word.

So the output should be:

```
L = [['I'], ['like'], ['candy'], ['end'], ['do'], ['you'], ['new_word']]
```

How do I change one of these duplicate words? I have tried the `str.replace()` method and referring to the specific duplicate with its index, but that changes all of the duplicates. What should I do? This is my first major project in python, so I'm a beginner.

Comment: why does `['okay']` disappear from your final list?

Comment: Perhaps start with the `list` section of a python tutorial? (Not trying to be dismissive, but it appears you're getting stuck on very rudimentary operations, and SO isn't best suited for that kind of question.)

Comment: I don't mind answering simple questions with nice oneliners and get a ton of upvotes from it, but here it's just unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
def see_two_end(l, stop_word, new_word):
    count = 0
    for sublist in l:
        if sublist[0] == stop_word:
            count += 1
        if count > 1:
            break
        yield sublist
    yield [new_word]

l = [['I'], ['like'], ['candy'], ['end'], ['do'], ['you'], ['end'], ['okay'], ['end']]

newlist = list(see_two_end(l, 'end', 'new_word'))
#[['I'], ['like'], ['candy'], ['end'], ['do'], ['you'], ['new_word']]
```

You could easily make `see_two_end` a function that returns a list of lists instead of a generator, if you perfer.